# Parse web.config globalization into a jQuery calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-config

Using ASPX, is there any way I can parse the short-hand date output of this (in the web.config)...

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

...into this JavaScript (part of a jQuery UI Calendar) (in a file named "Exit.aspx")...

```
 function calender() {
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: '[output goes here]' });
 }
```

So, in this case, the date sting output is dd/mm/yy. If I were to change the culture to, say, en-US, it would become mm/dd/yy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to set culture.

This can be done in code in page load:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
```

or setting the culture at page level using :

```
<%@ Page UICulture="en-GB" Culture="en-GB" %>
```

Or like you did with globalization element in web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

Then you page needs this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

Which we will use your to set it on the control

```
function calender() {
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: '<%=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern%>' });
}
```

Or using an specific culture:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

There are other options just in case: :

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern
```

Comment: Hm, small problem with the first code. It's outputting "dd/MM/yyyy", which, in jQuery, comes out as 01/January/2014.

Comment: It is because it is based on Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture

Comment: @Ducky I just tested with web.config and several cultures and it worked fine.

Comment: For some reason, at this end, with the culture set to "en-GB", and using `[...].DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern%>`, it's coming out as `({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy' });`
 in the JS, which is making the datepicker's text box produce "01/January/20142014".

Comment: Of do you mean year twice?

Comment: This may look a bit odd but it is because jquery plug in accepts only 2 characters for year, I think it would be OK to: .ShortDatePattern.Replace("yyyy","yy")

Comment: .ShortDatePattern.ToLower().Replace("yyyy","yy")

Comment: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToLower().Replace("yyyy","yy")

Comment: Yep, that works perfectly. Thanks!
_If only we all used YYYY-MM-DD_.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery localization files can be accessed from below mentioned location:

http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.i18n

Comment: instead of sharing links it will be better if you explain with an example.